# eloquent relationship between more than 3 tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, view, eloquent, relationship

Model complaints

```
class complaints extends Model {

        public function broad_categorys()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo(Broad_category::class);
        }
        public function referred_programs()
        {
          return $this->hasMany(Referred_program::class);
        }
        public function specific_categorys()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo(Specific_category::class);
        }
        public function provinces()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo(Provinces::class);
        }
        public function districts()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo(Districts::class);
        } 
}
```

Model Referred_to

```
class Referred_program extends Model 
{
  public function complaints() {   
    return $this->belongsTo(Complaints::class); 
  }
}
```

Model Broad_category

```
class broad_category extends Model 
{ 
  public function complaints() {  
    return $this->hasOne(Complaints::$this);
  }
}
```

Specific_category Model

```
class specific_category extends Model 
{
  public function complaints() {
    return $this->hasOne(Complaints::$this);
  }
}
```

This is edit view which I want to use the data of referred_to , Specific_category, and Broad_category

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <select name="broad_category" id="broad_category" class="form-control">
  @foreach($data->broad_categorys == $category)
    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->broad_cat_name}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You have Complaint belongs to a Broad_category, that means only one Broad_category will be returned to you, but in your view you are expecting more than one.

Comment: I am new in laravel and don't know what kind of relationship I should use. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

There are one to one, one to many, many to many, and then polymorphic. Perhaps you are looking for a many to many relationship, so that a Complaint has many Broad Categories, and Broad Categories have many Complaints. Since you have a many to many your going to need a lookup table. See the docs, or comment again if you need more.

Comment: I make the relation hasMany but it has error (Undefined offset: 1)I dont know this error I searched alot but could not solve it.